# adding row dyanamicaly to gridview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Please help me with the following code,I want to add a row inputted by user to a gridview.
I am able to add a row but its empty!!Please help.it worked in windows forms but its not working with WPF.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GetGridView();
        }
        private void GetGridView()
        {

      string[] row0 = {textBox1.Text,"Beatles" };

            dataGrid1.Items.Add(row0); 
            dataGrid1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = 0;
            dataGrid1.Columns[1].DisplayIndex = 1;

     }
```

//////////////
sure,here it is

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="964">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="274" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="509,12,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="239" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemStringFormat="{Binding}" SelectedIndex="-1" SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header1" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,187,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,125,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,66,0,0" Name="textBox4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="414,231,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Could you please add the Xaml or other defining code of the DataGrid, maybe the error is to be found there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: You bound the ItemsSource of the DataGrid, you cannot add items to the grid itself while that is the case, add the items to the bound collection (which is what i originally suggested)

---

I would not suggest you do anything like that. In WPF you should [bind your controls](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms752347.aspx&rct=j&q=databinding%20overview&ei=BsstTbnxLZDIswbD3c3oBw&usg=AFQjCNGXjYHofqVtsm7lnIHdV9MsiaToWA&sig2=R9y85iHL1wiKB59aoaQPbQ&cad=rja) to the data, that way you can change the source-collection and the grid will get updated automatically, which is less messy than using any method like `DataGrid.Items.Add` which accepts input of type `object`.

e.g.
Xaml:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GridData}" Name="DGrid"/>
    <TextBox Name="TB" Width="100"/>
    <Button Content="Add" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

Code:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Employee> gridData = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> GridData
    {
        get { return gridData; }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridData.Add(new Employee(TB.Text, "Beatles?"));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The original problem I am working on is actually different.I am totally confused as to how to implement it,So I was just trying to see if i could display the user data atleast in a gridView.

Comment: Could U please suggest me a better way of doing it.Here is my problem

Comment: I have to develop a tool in visual Studio about a Chemical Analysis Tool kinda similar to Turbo Tax Software.This tool asks the user some questions about the chemical composition of the product and some production data during the run time.On the basis of the values entered by the user,it does some calculations(some Big calculations) on the back end and prints/pdfs a report(in form of tables/Charts) 
Software Used: Visual Studio 2010, C#

Comment: According to my search online,I could use iTextSharp but I could not write the code for that.

Comment: Thins sounds way too general and at the very least would need to be split up into a few different questions, for each you'd need to specify exactly where you have a problem, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. My first question would be if WPF is a good choice for implementing such an application ?

Comment: You should not ask me but the stack-overflow community (if your questions conform with the guidelines), also, if my answer above answered the question about the DataGrid you can mark it as such my clicking the checkmark outline on the left side below the votes.